Down arrow key doesn't repeat in Xubuntu 24.04
I have a rather strange problem in Xubuntu 24.04: when I hold down the down arrow key it does not repeat. I set up key repeating and it works fine with every other key but the down arrow. I have Thinkpad X1 Carbon, the down arrow key is keycode 116.
$ xmodmap -pke |grep Down
…
keycode 116 = Down NoSymbol Down NoSymbol Down
…

This is some weird problem, I've never seen anything like it. Could anyone at least point me as to what should I look at?

Title and text say Ubuntu 22.04 but you have 24.04 flagged. Which is correct.  BTW have you ever had the down arrow auto repeat?

Thanks for the correction, I changed it. 24.04 is correct. It's the first time I've installed any Linux distro on this particular computer, as such I don't know if this problem is distro specific or anything. This computer came with windows 10 and there was no such problem in it.

You don't say much about the keyboard.  Is it a desktop keyboard (which can easily be swapped) or a laptop keyboard?  Assuming the worst, cannot be swapped, try booting from an XUbuntu try/install thumb drive.  If that also does not repeat the down key, the problem is your keyboard or system BIOS and not an issue with the operating system.
